# Wrong url regex keeps django busy

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have urls where spaces are replaced with the "-" character.
So I made a url regex like this:

```
url(r'^(?P<item_url>(\w+-?)*)/$', 'detail'),
```

my view:

```
def detail(request, item_url):
   i = get_object_or_404(Page, url=item_url,published=True)
   return render_to_response('item/detail.html', {'item':i},
       context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Unfortunately this keeps django extremely busy on urls with more than 20 characters. The process hangs for 20sec - 1 minute and then returns the correct result. Is this based on a wrong regex I'm using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following url pattern:

```
url(r'^(?P<item_url>[\w-]+)/$', 'detail'),
```

`[\w-]+` will match one or more alphanumeric characters or hyphens.

Comment: This works, thank you very much! Any idea why my regex hangs?

Comment: In your regex, `(\w+-?)` means a group of 1 or more alphanumeric characters, followed by zero or 1 hyphens. Then the `*` matches means zero or many of those groups. It's more complex that my regex, but I don't see why it would hang for as long as you saw.